# c++ asio socket read answer from server

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I got simple server-client app.

The idia is:
Client send to server string with sql-request.
Server process the request and send back on client answer with data formated in csv style string.

Everything is already adjusted accept one thing. The problem is to read answer on client cause I don't know the size of recieved string.

Code is bellow:

Server:

```
std::string answer;
answer = sql_read(*msg); //get the string with data from request
clientSock->write_some(buffer(answer, answer.size())); //send it back on client
```

Client:

```
std::string answer;
bytesRead = sock->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(readBuf, inputSize)); //read the answer, but how do I know correct size of string?
string_ptr msg(new std::string(readBuf, bytesRead));
answer = *msg;
```

How to read the resulting string without knowing its size?
Or if my aproach (with sending data in string) is radically wrong how to do it in correct way?

Comment: Tip: `clientSock->write_some()` might not write all the data. You have to check the return value and call it in a loop. Asio has a helper function to avoid this inconvenience. E.g.: `boost::asio::write(sock, boost::asio::buffer(answer));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must handle this yourself in the protocol the client and server use to speak to each other.

One way is to use a deliminator and use `boost::asio::read_until()`. Example:

```
boost::asio::streambuf buf;
boost::asio::read_until (sock, buf, "\r\n");  // or '\0' if zero terminated
```

[Check the Boost.Asio documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until/overload1.html).

Another way is to send the size in an fixed length header before sending the variable length part.

Answer (score 0):

You won't know the size of the string in advance. Where you do the read_some you will need to do a loop to read all the data from the socket. You need to check the number of bytes read and the size of the buffer you allocated. If they are equal then you filled up your read buffer and you need to do another read to check for any remaining data.